# upgrade PWA in background

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a challenge in my PWA. because of performance issues, I can't download all js files in the initial load, so each page, download its chunk, in loading time. in this case, if I deploy a new version and the previous' deploy chunk isn't downloaded yet, deploy time active users, will find a crash on application.
I need to know , is there any way to download all chunks and update PWA in background in service workers?

Answer (score 0):

Under some scenarios, you could use [Periodic Background Sync](https://web.dev/periodic-background-sync/) to keep cached data up to date via periodic refreshes. However, it's not intended as a way to allow you to cache critical resources for your web app—think of it more as a way of making optional, nice-to-have, updates.

If you have resources that need to be cached, and those resources are all versioned together, they should all be added to the cache inside of an [`install` handler](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#install).

If you can't download all files inside of that `install` handler then I think you need to reconsider whether using a service worker is the right approach for you, because there's no guarantee that you'll end up with a consistent cache using a different approach.

One workaround that you might consider is to show a "Loading..." or "Download assets..." splash screen when a user first comes to your web app, before they can interact with it, and while that screen is up, register your service worker and allow it to populate its caches inside its `install` handler. Once the `install` handler completes, you can then remove the "Loading..." screen and allow your users to interact with your web app.